# How can I create a dynamic row based on the query result in SQL (ORACLE)?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, window-functions

| COLOR | VARIANT |
| --- | --- |
| RED | BURGUNDY |
| RED | CRIMSON |
| GREEN | OLIVE |
| GREEN | EMERALD |

How can I query the above table as:

| RED | GREEN |
| --- | --- |
| BURGUNDY | OLIVE |
| CRIMSON | EMERALD |

So far, I've looked into PIVOT, but most examples I found are related to average and count. Can you please direct me to any resources that I should look into. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a column that can be used to order the records, say `id`, you can use window functions to enumerate the rows of each color, then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(case when color = 'RED'  then variant end) red,
    max(case when color = 'BLUE' then variant end) blue
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by color order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn
```